# Unable to import required module for interfacing with Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, boost, distutils

I am using boost 1.49 ( also tried 1.53 ) on Ubuntu 12.04, and Django 1.3. I need to compile a C++ module using distutils, and use this in the Django app. It was working fine, till I introduced mongoDB calls in the C++ program. Now the module compiles, but I keep getting the error

Could not import `<app_nam>.views. Error was: libmongoclient.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE`

I have been trying to get around this for past 2 days, with no avail. I have included all the boost libraries in the **setup.py** I am using to build the extension module, and have included the file paths.

Comment: You don't say which version of mongodb-dev you installed, but the default on 12.04 is MongoDB 2.0.4. This version  depends on boost 1.46.1 (mongodb 2.4 depends on 1.49.0). There is also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611845/boost-not-statically-linking-in-to-boostpython-shared-object), which might help.